# cookies asp.net at debug time

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET app, it run fine after publish the site on my own machine, but if I try to debug the app, all cookies appear as a null object.

Some Ideas?

Comment: You need to give more details about your problem, maybe add some screenshots with some request, so we can see what could be wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because you do not have correctly setup the domain, on the web.config for cookies, so the cookies is not saved. So check your web.config if you have correctly setup this line:

```
<httpCookies domain="debugname.com"  />
```

Comment: Very tks. I'm trying at this time.

Comment: I can't find this section on my web.config, where it must be ?

Comment: Very tks for your help. StackOverflow rocks